# Serving index.html from nginx but keep file links intact through rewriting(?)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to have nginx serve an index.html (if present) from inside a specific (sub-)subfolder. The problem is that this kind of works but when requesting the folder without a slash at the end will serve the index.html from that subfolder but subsequently break any linked files from that index.

My nginx config looks like this:

```
location ^~ /folder {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html =404;
}
location / {
    ...do regular website stuff
}
```

/folder does not contain any files but a couple of subdirectories and these all have an index.html.
Things that work fine are:

- mywebsite.com: I get served the regular website
- mywebsite.com/folder: returns a 404
- mywebsite.com/folder/subfolder/: returns the index.html from that subfolder and all linked files (stylesheets, script, images, ...) are fine

However, what does not work correctly is: mywebsite.com/folder/subfolder (without the slash at the end). Then I get served the index.html from the subfolder but all linked files are broken because they point to /folder. So my best guess is that I need to rewrite the url to include a subsequent slash but my skill level in nginx configurations is not up to that task.

/as explained by Richard Smith, this did the trick:
try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;

Comment: Adding a `$uri/` term will automatically add a trailing `/` and automatically return `index.html` if one exists. So you could simply use `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;`

Comment: Ah, thank you. That did indeed the trick!